# PDF generation from templated Word documents

Tags: ms-word, pdf-generation

I have a Word document(some template format) where it containing some placeholders for the data to be filled in and there are several Word documents like this which lies in some directory. When data comes I will be choosing different templates (based on some criteria) and fill the data and the documents have to be converted to PDF format.

I have been investigating Apache POI for this. If anyone has a good suggestion, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your plan for filling in the data?  COM automation of Word?

Comment: @mbeckish i have plan to fill the data via POI (apache). i do read the paragraphs via HWPFDoc api (poi) and then simply replaces the places holders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mbeckish mentioned you should indicate how you are going to run/automate this.  For example is it one-off, run by hand or part of another program (and if so what programming languages do you use)?

If you are trying to automate it [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) and [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) are tools that can use templates like you require and can produce PDF.  JODReports is free.  Docmosis is not but has several APIs.  Please note I work for the company that develops Docmosis.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i am using java. I have already done the text filling part via Apache POI. its api has it supportabillity. Thanks for the suggestion on JODReport i will have a look tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I've just uploaded [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/plutext/document-generation-2012osdcsydney), which presents three approaches for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use any of existing PDF virtual printers?